# NSTextView defaultParagraphStyle having no effect

Tags: cocoa, swift, desktop-application, nstextview

In my NSTextView subclass I have :

```
class EditorTextView: NSTextView {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        var theParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        theParagraphStyle.lineSpacing = 50
        self.defaultParagraphStyle = theParagraphStyle
```

Why could this be having no effect on the line spacing in the text view...?

Comment: If you set initial text, does this not display the text correctly? -- I have problems with user-entered text changing the paragraph style. But when I pass initial contents, these are displayed correctly (until the user changes stuff at the beginning of the paragraph).